# How to make fillField() work for functional tests Codeception + Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5, functional-testing, codeception, php-5.6

I am writing some functional tests to test login system for my application. I tried below ways to use `fillField()` but couldn't make it work for me.

```
$I->fillField(['id' => 'loginEmail'], 'sample@mail.com');
```

and

```
$I->fillField("//input[@id='loginEmail']", 'sample@mail.com');
```

After that, when i tried to run `seeInFormFields()` method, its giving me below error:

```
 Step  I see in form fields "form[name=loginForm]",{"email":"sample@mail.com","password":123456}
 Fail  Failed asserting that `sample@mail.com` is in input's value: array (
  0 => '',
)
Failed asserting that an array contains 'sample@mail.com'.
```

Point to be noted that, i have signup form on same page which has same `name`, thats why i had to use `ID`.

Any help or suggestion will be much appreciated.

**UPDATE WITH HTML CODE**

Below is my HTML form code

```
<form name="loginForm" class="" method="POST" action="https://domain/en-us/checkout/login">
        <div class="col-sm-12 wrapper generic-form collapse-form" ng-controller="mobileController">
            <fieldset>
                <legend
                    class="legend-login">
                    I have an account
                </legend>
                <div class="collapse-panel">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 control-group">
                        <div class="row form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : loginForm.email.$error.required && submitted }">
                            <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 text-right">
                                <label for="email">E-Mail</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
                                <input
                                        name="email"
                                        type="email" class="form-control"
                                        id="loginEmail"
                                        required>
                                <small class="ico-buttons ico-error red">
                                    Mandatory
                                </small>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <div class="row form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : loginForm.password.$error.required && submitted }">
                            <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 text-right">
                                <label for="password">Password</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
                                <input  name="password"
                                        type="password"
                                        class="form-control"
                                        id="password"
                                        required>
                                <small class="ico-buttons ico-error red">
                                    Mandatory
                                </small>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <div class="row form-group">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-4">
                                <input type="button" value="Login" name="submitWelcomeLoginForm">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                                <br>
                                <a href='https://domain.com/' class='pull-right'>Forgot Password?</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Could you add HTML of your form to question?

Comment: @Naktibalda did you take a look at my html code??

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter is string name of the field

```
$I->fillField('email', 'sample@mail.com');
```

You can find many test scripts here: https://github.com/satrun77/tinyissue/blob/master/tests/functional

Test script used `fillField`
https://github.com/satrun77/tinyissue/blob/master/tests/functional/CrudIssueCest.php

Comment: just take a look http://codeception.com/docs/modules/Laravel5#fillField . I can also use it like array and use other parameters right?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not that fillField doesn't work,
it is that seeInFormFields does not see filled values, it only sees values present in the original HTML of the page.

Comment: don't use seeInFormFields, have you got an issue with submitting form?